# How add a migration to a EntityFramework 7 project

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm starting a new project using asp.net 5 and EF 7 VS2015.

I selected the project template with the user mangagement.
Now I want to add some classes to the dbContext and have a new schema created with my new classes.

This is wat my ApplicationDbContext looks like:

```
    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public DbSet<Candidate> Candidates { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Manager> Managers { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        // Customize the ASP.NET Identity model and override the defaults if needed.
        // For example, you can rename the ASP.NET Identity table names and more.
        // Add your customizations after calling base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        builder.Entity<Candidate>().Key(x => x.Id);
        builder.Entity<Manager>().Key(x => x.Id);
    }
}
```

I have not been able to recreate or migrate my database to a version with  my `Candidates` and `Managers` table.

Which commands do I have to enter where to make my DB appear? My friend Google and Bing have pointed me in every direction, but none of the things I found worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the new `dnx` commands, for example:

```
dnx . ef migration add NameOfMigration
```

And to run the migration:

```
dnx . ef migration apply
```

Comment: These commands have to be entered in the CMD console not the package manager console.

Comment: The "." stands for current directory so "CD" in  the console to point to your project directory

Answer (score 0):

I found this [CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/988763/Database-Migration-in-Entity-Framework) that shows how to deal with migration on ASP .NET 5 project but in summary you need to apply the commands that @DavidG recommended in his answer.

I know this is not your case, but if you were working with a *Class Library* project, then the commands you would need to run are these:

Open the *Package Manager Console*:

- Run `Add-Migration MigrationName` If it is the first time, it will to scaffold a migration to create the initial set of tables for your model, otherwise it will scaffold the next migration based on changes you have made to your model since the last migration was created.
- Run `Apply-Migration` to apply the new migration to the database.
  If your database doesn’t exist yet, it will be created for you
  before the migration is applied.

To apply these commands you need to configure a database provider first. You can do this by overriding `OnConfiguring` in your `DbContext` class or in the `AddDbContext` method when setting up services.

```
 protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
 {          
     optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(@"Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=EFGetStarted.ConsoleApp;Trusted_Connection=True;");
 }
```

Comment: DbContextOptionsBuilder was not a known class when I added this code, R# was not able to resolve the needed usings. I have adjusted the connection string using project.json

Comment: @k.c., in the Code Project article is where I said you probably would find the solution to you issue. The second solution is in case you were working Class Library project to define your model.

Comment: thanks, I have it working now, atleast that part of it ;-)

Comment: @k.c. name of this class changed twice between beta4 and beta6. See this issue https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/41

Answer (score 0):

As per ASP.NET 5 and Entity 7 RC1 the steps would be:

1. Add a dependency to the Entity Commands nuget package in your main project. So in your `project.json` you should see this dependency
   `"EntityFramework.Commands": "7.0.0-rc1-final"`
2. Add an alias command to use from console later on. So in your `project.json` you would have the following `ef` command:

   `"commands": {
         "ef": "EntityFramework.Commands",
          "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel"
      }`
3. Open a console and run the migration commands. For example:

   `D:\Projects\MyProject\src\MyProject.Web.Api>dnx ef migrations add Initial --targetProject MyProject.Data.SqlServer`
4. Then review the Migration that `ef` will create in your project and apply the changes to your database (the database that is configured for your project) with the following command:

   `D:\Projects\MyProject\src\MyProject.Web.Api>dnx ef database update`

Notice that the attribute `--targetProject` allows you to specify the project where your DbContext is and where the folder Migrations would be created. If your DbContext is in your main project you can omit that (but I recommend to have a class library project for everything persistance related so this command would be handy)

In your `Startup.cs` is where you usually would have the configuration for Entity including the connection string. This is a basic example:

```
public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        // Set up configuration sources.
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();
        Configuration = builder.Build();
        builder.AddEnvironmentVariables();
        Configuration = builder.Build();
    }

    public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; private set; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Add framework services.
        services.AddEntityFramework()
            .AddSqlServer()
            .AddDbContext<KuneDbContext>(options => {
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["Data:DefaultConnection:ConnectionString"]);
            });

        // Add identity here http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/tutorials/your-first-aspnet-application.html

        services.AddMvc();

        // Add application services
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
        loggerFactory.AddDebug();

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseBrowserLink();
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");

            // For more details on creating database during deployment see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=615859
            try
            {
                using (var serviceScope = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>()
                    .CreateScope())
                {
                    serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetService<KuneDbContext>()
                         .Database.Migrate();
                }
            }
            catch { }
        }

        app.UseIISPlatformHandler();

        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });

        //Seed Data if you want to load some test data in the DB
        //SeedData.Initialize(app.ApplicationServices);
    }

    // Entry point for the application.
    public static void Main(string[] args) => WebApplication.Run<Startup>(args);
}
```